# Good introduction to <inttypes.h>

Tags: c, printf, c99

I want to recommend the use of `<inttypes.h>` to someone doing `printf` with mixed 32/64 bit builds.  I tried to Google an introduction or tutorial page with a few examples and usage guidelines, but I couldn't find one.

Can someone recommend an introduction or tutorial for `<inttypes.h>`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mixed 32/64 bit builds".  Will the user be expected to use the 'fixed size' types from `stdint.h`?  Is there something in particular lacking in Edwin's answer that led to the bounty being added?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, the issue arises when you use known-width integer types like `int64_t` under LP64 where that corresponds to `long`.  The proper format specifier is `%ld` in that case, but if you build on a 32-bit system where it corresponds to `long long` then you need `%lld`.  I was hoping for a description which both motivated the use of `<inttypes.h>` (as I briefly do in this comment) as well as providing examples.  Something I could point at to save myself having to explain the why and the how.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html for a start.

A better example of how to use the new portable formatting macros was found in [avr-libc](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__inttypes.html).  I've included an example (from the link) to illustrate.  [QNX libraries](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.4.1/dinkum_en/c99/inttypes.html#PRId8) also have a better human-readable description (if you don't like reading the specification cold), although you have to scroll nearly to the end of the page to get to the meat of the descriptions.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint8_t smallval;
int32_t longval;
...
printf("The hexadecimal value of smallval is %" PRIx8
       ", the decimal value of longval is %" PRId32 ".\n",
       smallval, longval);
```

Note that this uses the "String" "String" implied concatenation operator to yield the string (in this example)

```
"The hexadecimal value of smallval is %x, the decimal value of longval is %ld.\n"
```

An attempt to decompose the naming convention seems to indicate:

- (first three letters)

  - PRI for printf format
  - SCN for scanf format
- (fourth letter)

  - x for hexadecimal formatting
  - u for unsigned formatting
  - o for octal formatting
  - i for integer formatting
  - d for decimal formatting
- (extra letters)

  - 8 for eight bit
  - 16 for sixteen bit
  - 32 for thirty-two bit
  - 64 for sixty-four bit
  - FAST8 for "fast" eight bit
  - FAST16 for "fast" sixteen bit
  - FAST32 for "fast" thirty-two bit
  - FAST64 for "fast" sixty-four bit
  - LEAST8 for "least" eight bit
  - LEAST16 for "least" sixteen bit
  - LEAST32 for "least" thirty-two bit
  - LEAST64 for "least" sixty-four bit
  - PTR for pointer
  - MAX for maximum supported bit size

so `PRIx8` means printf format instruction to format to hexadecimal eight bits.

Comment: Ah, what a good use of putting string literals beside each other.

Comment: PTR is for pointer-sized _integers_ (size_t,intptr_t,ptrdiff_t), not pointers.  On at least one of my platforms (OSX), I get an error using PRIxPTR with void*.  Use %p for pointers.

Comment: @RickBerge: Note that strictly the PTR macros are for `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`; the C99 and C11 standards define the format modifier `z` to designate a `size_t` argument (hence `"%zu"`, for example), and they define `t` to designate a `ptrdiff_t` (hence `"%td"`, for example).

Answer (score 8):

I always go to the standard ([PDF link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)) for those things; they're not too complicated once you figure out the patterns they're set up in.  The relevant section is **§7.8 Format conversion of integer types `<inttypes.h>`**.

Answer (score 2):

HP Has a good reference on writing portable code and they give some specific advice for using inttypes.h

[Writing Portable Code](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/site/dspp/menuitem.863c3e4cbcdc3f3515b49c108973a801/?jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN&ciid=a868e67018695110VgnVCM100000275d6e10RCRD)

Answer (score 1):

I always start at Wikipedia to look up a header. [`<inttypes.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inttypes.h) seems to be very problematic on Wikipedia. The next step I would then take is going to [this site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html). This previous site lists every macro and does give an example. You could also check out [this site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html), which actually shows you the header file. I don't think that any of those are really tutorials per say  but they are a good jumping off point.

Comment: The last 2 links are the same (mostly just the list of macros)