# Format specifiers for implementation-defined types like time_t

Tags: c, printf, typedef, time-t

I want to make my code more platform-/implementation-independent. I don't know what a `time_t` will be implemented as on the platform when the code is being compiled. How do I know the type of `t` to determine what format specifier to use?

```
...
time_t t = time(NULL);
printf("%s", t);
...
```

Comment: In your non-portable way, is there even a guarantee that there's a null-terminator within valid memory?

Comment: That isn't really the question. Do you know the answer to the question I asked?

Comment: No, but absent of any portable solution, your non-portable solution should still not invoke UB.

Comment: It is just an example to make my question about the printing of types clearer.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508236/typedefs-and-printf-format-specifiers

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508236/typedefs-and-printf-format-specifiers , and for time_t in particular the situation is the same as for clock_t http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083142/what-s-the-correct-way-to-use-printf-to-print-a-clock-t

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, the way to display the value of a `time_t` is to break down its components to a `struct tm` using `gmtime` or `localtime` and display those or convert them as desired with `strftime`, or `ctime` to go directly from `time_t` to a string showing local time.

If you want to see the raw value for some purpose, the C standard specifies that `time_t` is *real*, which means it is integer or floating-point (C 2011 (N1570) 6.2.5 17). Therefore, you should be able to convert it to `double` and print that. There is some possibility that `time_t` can represent values that `double` cannot, so you might have to guard against that if you want to take care regarding exotic implementations. Since `difftime` returns the difference of two `time_t` objects as a `double`, it seems C does not truly support `time_t` with more precision than a `double`.

Comment: I don't think anything in the standard forbids making `time_t` equivalent to `long double`. It would just mean that the result of `difftime()` might be imprecise. `difftime()` can lose precision anyway if `time_t` and `double` are both 64 bits.

Answer (score 29):

Usually you can use a cast to convert the operand to some type for which you know the right format.

Your proposed solution:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
printf("%s", t);
```

clearly will *not* work, since `time_t` is a numeric type, not `char*`.

We know, in general, that `time_t` is an arithmetic type. Something like this:

```
 printf("%ld\n", (long)t);
```

is likely to work on most systems. It can fail (a) if `time_t` is an unsigned type no wider than `unsigned long` and the current value of `t` exceeds `LONG_MAX`, or (b) if `time_t` is a floating-point type.

If you have C99 support, you can use `long long`, which is a little better:

```
printf("%lld\n", (long long)t);
```

If you really want to go overboard with portability, you can detect what kind of type `time_t` is:

```
if ((time_t)-1 > 0) {
    // time_t is an unsigned type
    printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)t);
}
else if ((time_t)1 / 2 == 0) {
    // time_t is a signed integer type
    printf("%jd\n", (intmax_t)t);
}
else {
    // time_t is a floating-point type (I've never seen this)
    printf("%Lg\n", (long double)t);
}
```

You might want to tweak the `%Lg` format to something like `%Lf` or `%.10Lf`, depending on what output format you want.

Again, this assumes C99 support -- and you'll need `#include <stdint.h>` to make `uintmax_t` and `intmax_t` visible.

`time_t` and `clock_t` are a bit unusual, in that the standard says *only* that they're arithmetic type capable of representing times. (In principle they could be complex types, but I'd say ignoring that possibility is worth the risk.)

In most other cases, you'll probably know whether a given type is signed, unsigned, or floating-point, and you can just convert to the widest type of that kind.

Note that if you don't know how `time_t` is represented, you probably won't understand the output of the `printf` (such as `1379375215`) either -- unless your goal is to figure that out.

(If you were programming in C++ rather than C, `std::cout << t << "\n";` would automatically use the correct overloaded `operator<<`.)

If you want *human-readable* output (like `Mon 2013-09-16 16:46:55 PDT`), you'll want to use one of the conversion functions declared in `<time.h>`, such as `asctime()` or `strftime()`.

Comment: What does this line mean --> "if ((time_t)-1 > 0) {" ? (thank you)

Comment: @Moytaba: That condition is true if and only if `time_t` is an unsigned integer type. Converting a negative value (`-1`) to an unsigned type yields a positive results.

Comment: I think you meant `(time_t)1 / 2 == 0` or similar for (signed) integer versus floating discrimination

Answer (score 11):

You can use `difftime()` to obtain a `double`:

```
time_t t = time(NULL);
printf("seconds 1970->now: %.f\n", difftime(t, (time_t) 0));
```

It is simple and I think it is portable.

Comment: This is by far the best solution. It is also very simple and portable (Linux, FreeBSD).

Answer (score 3):

The C standard says `time_t` will be a 'real type' (meaning an integer type or a floating point type, though in practice it is always an integer type).

With `time_t`, your best bet is to format it with `strftime()` after analyzing it with `localtime()` or `gmtime()` — this can be done portably.

Unportably, you have to determine by some mechanism what is the correct format specifier.  You might use `PRI_[Xxodi]_time` and `SCN_[Xxodi]_time` or something similar as a non-standard but close-to-standard (without trampling on the reserved namespace — which is names starting PRI or SCN followed by a lower-case letter or X).  You use some mechanism to specify that...encapsulating the unportable information in one place.