# Printing time_t as long int without casting gives unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c, datetime

I am trying to print time_t without casting it as long int in Microsoft Visual Studio Project and it is giving me unexpected result. The source code is

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int a=1,b=2;
    long int c=3;
    time_t myTime;
    time(&myTime);
    printf("%d_%ld_%d_%ld",a,myTime,b,c);
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is `1_1389610399_0_2`. This is running fine on my linux machine though.I understand that time_t should not be printed like this but I am not sure why? Please tell me how to debug such problem?

**EDIT:** I was expecting the output to be `1_1389610399_2_3` given the fact that `time_t` is considered as arithmetic in C.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You know you are printing it incorrectly, yet wonder why it doesn't do what you expect? What output do you want?

Comment: The time_t type in C is considered to be arithmetic type. So,the expected output should be something like 1_1389610399_2_3. I am not getting it why the output is coming the way it is coming.

Comment: @Abhishek: By the looks of your results (I haven't checked the docs) `time_t` is `long long` on Windows, which would be sensible. When you pass the wrong types as varargs, things go wrong.

Comment: Why shouldn't a time be printed like that? Who told you that? While `time_t` might be something else (it's implementation specified) on platforms where it is an integer it can indeed be printed like that. It won't really tell you anything except that it's a large number, but otherwise it's okay. You just have to be careful to output it using the correct format code (or use the C++ output operator `<<`).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No.  On platforms where `time_t` is a `long`, it can be printed like that.  If it's a `long long` (e.g. as in 32 bit Visual), then it can't be.

Comment: Use `%lld`. http://rextester.com/live/OEAXN43132

Comment: Read here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time_t/

Comment: @ramyabel: I dont think that will be correct. Since from the answeres I think it is platform dependent.

Comment: @Abhishek I picked the `vc++` compiler because you're on Windows. Using `%lld` instead of `%ld` is the correct argument for it to get correct output, because Windows uses a long long while Linux uses a long.

Comment: Actually I am working on a project which will run on various platforms, windows: both 64 and 32 bits and linux. Hence, the implementation of time_t will be different on all of those. %lld will not solve my problem. I will have to cast it to known type.

Comment: @Abhishek If you know it's implementation-specific, then why ask the question?

Comment: @remyabel: I just knew it after reading the answeres :D. Please don't get offended. Thanks for your response. I should have been more clear in the question about using different architectures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839043/format-specifiers-for-implementation-defined-types-like-time-t

Comment: @Abhishek Why did you want code to avoid a cast to `long int`?  Was it that you did not want to use a cast or that you did not want the result to be `long int`?

Comment: @chux I don't remember man. It's been long, and I have since left the beautiful universe of C to make way for Python and JavaScript. May be, I might have asked out of curiosity. I must have fixed it by casting it appropriately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was expecting the output to be `1_1389610399_2_3`

You are wrong to expect this. Different types have different sizes, and when you pass the "wrong" type via varargs this means that the receiver can no longer find everything on the stack in the expected locations. That's why behavior is undefined when the formatting codes don't match the arguments: the receiver is not reading the same types that the caller is writing.

The `0` that you see printed out where you expected `b`, is the most significant 32 bits of the 64-bit `long long` value that is placed on the stack when you pass a `time_t` via varargs (in this implementation). The `%ld` formatting code only took the first 4 bytes of the value of `myTime`, leaving the rest to be taken by the next formatting code.

When it works on linux, that's because `time_t` is `long` on that implementation and so your format code matches the type you pass.

There is a kind of "all-purpose" way to print any signed integer, which is to convert it to `intmax_t` and use the formatting code `%j`. Unfortunately you aren't guaranteed that `time_t` is a signed type, or even that it's an integer type. So this would be *more* portable but still not strictly so, because the value of `myTime` *in theory* might not be in range of `intmax_t` at all. In C++ you should use `std::cout << myTime;`, because that avoids you needing to know the actual type aliased by `time_t` (just as long as it's not any kind of `char`).

Alternatively you can use `difftime` to coerce your time to `double`, which you know how to print. Or you can use `gmtime` or `localtime` to get a broken-down calendar time, each component of which you know how to print either with `printf` or with `strftime`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer @steve, but shouldn't according to this logic, printf("%d_%ld_%d",a,b,c); should have given output as 1_2_0, but instead it is given output as 1_2_3.

Comment: @Abhishek: no. `int` and `long` are the same size on Windows. It's still undefined behavior, of course.

Answer (score 9):

Who says `time_t` is a `long`?  It may be any arithmetic type.
You must explicitly cast it to some defined type when using
`printf`.

Use `ostream`, and avoid such problems.

Comment: But how my not casting it is affecting the subsequent argument of b? I fail to understand this.

Comment: @Abhishek Because you're passing the wrong type to a var_args.  Which causes the var args mechanism to become unsynchronized with your input.  (The usual mechanism involves adding the size of the extracted element to a `char*` to get the address of the next element.)  You _must_ pass the exact type the receiving program expects to a var args.

Comment: Thanks @James, It is clear to me now. I will look more into printf implementation and var args mechanism to get more insight.

Answer (score 2):

To show its (`time_t`) contents in a safe manner, you should first use (ie.) `gmtime` to convert it to `struct tm`, and then use one of its fields or use `strftime` to convert it further to string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print a 64 bit integer using a format string you have to use `%I64d` rather than `%ld`.
However, be ware because the type of `time_t` depends on your hardware's bitness.

Answer (score 0):

the time() function returns the number of seconds elapsed "since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC".

Source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t

So, the value you got (1389610399) is pretty fine, as it is:

1389610399 / 60 (=minutes) / 60 (=hours) / 24 (=days) / 365 ~ 44 years, which seems pretty plausible.

So, if you want to get the number of days, for example, then divide the time-value by 3600.
If you want to get the date, then refer to other functions such as localtime() or gmtime() - the latter returns the date and time in UTC. See the examples provided at:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/gmtime

Hope that helps!
Greetz,
Michael