# correct format specifiers for exact-width integer types

Tags: c, types, formatting

I am somewhat new to C. Below is code I wrote to use unsigned exact-width integers. However, when using scanf() I am not sure how to specify the correct format for uint8_t.

When attempting to compile the code, I get the following kind of warning:

> red_black_tree.c:14:2: warning: format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 
>   2 has type ‘uint8_t *’ [-Wformat]

The code follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> /*printf, scanf, NULL*/
#include <stdlib.h> /*malloc, free, rand*/
#include <stdint.h> /*type support*/

int main(){

   uint8_t i, number, *A;

   printf("specify length of array:");
    scanf("%i", &i);

   A = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*i);

   for(number=0; number < i; number ++){
            scanf("%i", &(A[i]) );
    }

   free(A);
}
```

Comment: No, not a duplicate, unless we use a different lexicon... I found this answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299323/good-introduction-to-inttypes-h --ttfn

Comment: The originally proposed duplicate did not cover the scan specifiers. I have proposed the duplicate found by the OP, which only asks about the print specifiers but is answered with coverage of both print and scan specifiers.