# How to avoid -fpermissive?

Tags: c++, pointers

I wrote the following code example and I've had to use -fpermissive to skip the error/warning

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int endOfProgram(){
    printf("\n\npress return key to close the program...");
    char end[2];
    fgets(end, 2, stdin);
    return 0;
}

void pointerTest(vector<int> * pointer){
    printf("%d\n", pointer);
    printf("%#x\n", (unsigned)pointer);
    for (auto it = (*pointer).begin(); it < (*pointer).end(); it++)
        printf("%d ", *it);
}

int main(){
    vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    pointerTest(&numbers);
    endOfProgram();
}
```

error/warning message:

```
@test:~/workspace $ make
g++ -std=c++11 pointerTest.cc -o pointerTest -fpermissive
pointerTest.cc: In function ‘void pointerTest(std::vector<int>*)’:
pointerTest.cc:13:24: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘std::vector<int>*’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%d\n", pointer);
                        ^
pointerTest.cc:14:28: warning: cast from ‘std::vector<int>*’ to ‘unsigned int’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
  printf("%#x\n", (unsigned)pointer);
                            ^
```

obviously these two lines are problematic...

```
printf("%d\n", pointer);
printf("%#x\n", (unsigned)pointer);
```

**the question:** How can I write these lines, in order to avoid using -fpermissive?

Comment: `std::cout << pointer`

Comment: Or `printf("%p\n", pointer);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special escape for pointers:

```
printf("%p\n", pointer);
```

Alternatively, but strictly less preferred:

```
printf("%lu\n", uintptr_t(pointer));
```

The former would print something like `0x7fffc3488bbc` while the latter would print a decimal version `140736469699516`.

Comment: `%lu` means `unsigned long`. The proper format specifier for `uintptr_t` is the macro `PRIuPTR` defined in `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: @Brian I'll worry about being cross platform when I have to... for now `"%lu\n"` is way more obvious than `"%" PRIuPTR "\n"`.

Comment: thanks... so basically `printf("%" PRIuPTR "\n", uintptr_t(pointer));` would make it cross platform?

Comment: @Ubica Yep. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6299346/2069064) for more info.

Comment: The problem with barry's answer is that `lu` is not always the size of `uintptr_t` on all platforms.  What worse is that if `ul` is larger, you get a random chunk of stack printed, and if `ul` is smaller and you have other arguments printed, you could crash.  Don't treat formatting arguments casually.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use `%d` to print out a pointer. It's undefined behaviour.
2. Use the `%p` format specifier to print out a pointer, rather than trying to cast it to an integer.