# How can i print a pointer that takes a void function?

Tags: c, pointers, printf, void

I have a main.c code (cannot be changed) :

```
int main() {
  uint8_t *param ;
  param = func(key) ; 
}
```

Key is an array of 16 elements and func is declared in a stud.c that is linked to main by stud.h. the func() is declared as follows

```
void *func(void *key){//some code}
```

Now how can i print param ? i have tried multiple options with printf . Is there any suggestion plZ ? I need the param as an array of 16 elements in hex format  also. I cannot change anything in main.c (i cannot change any type!!!)

```
for(int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
    printf("%02X ", param[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: To be sure you're correctly printing stuff defined in `stdint.h`, try `printf("%02"PRIX8" ", param[j]);` adding `#include <inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print uint32\_t and uint16\_t variables value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120426/how-to-print-uint32-t-and-uint16-t-variables-value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    printf("%02" PRIu8 "\n", param[i]);
}
```

since your array is of type `uint8_t`.

Do not forget to `#include <inttypes.h>`.

Read more in [Good introduction to <inttypes.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299323/good-introduction-to-inttypes-h), where other naming conventions are explained, e.g. `PRIx8` if you want to print the hexadecimal value.

Comment: Somewhere else in your code @CeasarDll. I think I answered your question. If I were you, I would accept this answer (since it's correct), and try debugging my program, by using a debugger (like `gdb` for example). Then, if I still needed help, I would create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post a *new* question.